# Animate rounded border lines on hover with CSS

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to create a button hover animation where the border lines are animated. Does anyone know if its possible to animate the rounded corners with css or do I need to create an svg animation instead?
See the codepen bellow:

See the Pen [Button Border Hover Effect](https://codepen.io/lipovskoy/pen/qJGXOx/) by Anton Lipovskoy ([@lipovskoy](https://codepen.io/lipovskoy)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans);
*, *:after, *:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background: #004b60;
}
.container{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
button{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 210, 195, 1);
  border-radius: 0.175rem;
   -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
span{
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}
button::before, button::after{
  content:"";
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 210, 195, 1);
  border-radius: 0.175rem;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

span::before, span::after{
  content:"";
  width:1px;
  height:0;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 210, 195, 1);
  border-radius: 0.175rem;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
button:hover::before, button:hover::after{
  width: 100%;
}
button:hover{
background: rgba(0, 210, 195, 0.1);
  color:rgba(0, 210, 195, 1);
  }
button:hover span::before, button:hover span::after{
  height: 100%;
}

/*----- button 4 -----*/
.btn-4::after{
  right:0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;

}
.btn-4 span::after{
  right:0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;

}
.btn-4::before{
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;

}
.btn-4 span::before{
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn-4"><span>Hover Me</span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: In transition instead of all try border-radius.

Comment: Border *lengths* cannot be affected by CSS...only widths. SVG would probably be the most effective method. I that what you are asking?

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will have to do a svg animation then.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make it work with `border-radius` and `width`, `height`. You can change it's border radius to your input. 
May be it will help you to get what you want.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans);
*, *:after, *:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background: #004b60;
}
.container{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
button{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 210, 195, 1);
  border-radius: 15px;
   -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
span{
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}
button::before{  
  border-top:1px solid rgba(0,210, 195, 1);
  border-radius:0px;
  border-top-left-radius:0px;
  border-top-right-radius:0;
  
  border-bottom-right-radius:0;
  border-bottom-left-radius:0;
}
button::after{  
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,210, 195, 1);
  border-radius:0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:0;
  border-bottom-left-radius:0;
  border-top-left-radius:0;
  border-top-right-radius:0;
  
}
button::before, button::after{
  content:"";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  /*background: rgba(0, 210, 195, 1);*/
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
span::before {
  border-left:1px solid rgba(0,210, 195, 1);
  border-radius:0;
  
  border-top-left-radius:0px;
  border-top-right-radius:0;
  
  border-bottom-right-radius:0;
  border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
}
span::after {
  border-right:1px solid rgba(0,210, 195, 1);
  border-radius:0;
  
  border-top-left-radius:0;
  border-top-right-radius:0px;
  
  border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:0;
}

span::before, span::after{
  content:"";
  width:0;
  height:0;
  position: absolute;
  /*background: rgba(0, 210, 195, 1);*/
  border-radius: 15px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
button:hover::before, button:hover::after{
  width: 100%;
  height:35px;
}

button:hover::before{
  left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius:15px;
}

button:hover::after{
  right: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
}
button:hover{
background: rgba(0, 210, 195, 0.1);
  color:rgba(0, 210, 195, 1);
  }
button:hover span::before, button:hover span::after{
  height: 100%;
  width:55px;
}
button:hover span::before{
  top:0;
  border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
}
button:hover span::after {
  bottom:0;
  
  border-top-right-radius:15px;
}

/*----- button 4 -----*/
.btn-4::after{
  right:10px;
  bottom: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;

}
.btn-4 span::after{
  right:0;
  bottom: 10px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;

}
.btn-4::before{
  left: 10px;
  top: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  
}
.btn-4 span::before{
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn-4"><span>Hover Me</span></button>
</div>
```

You can also test it [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BqgvqX)

I would still believe SVG as a most effective method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try to tweak it but you are probably right, creating a SVG animation is better.